# Ruby array of arrays to hash with first item as key

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of arrays (result of "pluck" usage) in following form:

```
arr = [[1, 'A1', 'B1'],[2, 'A2', 'B2'],[3, 'A3', 'B3']]
```

How to get following hash from it?

```
{1=>[1, 'A1', 'B1'], 2=>[2, 'A2', 'B2'], 3=>[3, 'A3', 'B3']}
```

I know this form, but surely there is one line form, too

```
hash = Hash.new

arr.each do |x|
  hash[x[0]] = x
end
```

Comment: Personally I like the form you posted just fine - it is probably the most readable and _nearly_ the most compact even if some other incantations might squeeze out a few characters. I'd be inclined to just put it on one line in the {} form `arr.each { |x| hash[x[0]] = x}`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'd be inclined to say `arr.group_by(&:first)` is more compact and more understandable.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes I agree, that's a slick implementation. I admit though if I found it in my codebase I'd have to go out to the Array#group_by docs to make sure I knew what it did.

Comment: `hash=arr.map{|sa| [sa[0],sa[1..]]}.to_h`

Comment: @dawg that will not produce the desired result as it will not retain element `sa[0]` in the value portion of the `Hash`

Comment: @dawg In my question I mentioned {1=>[1, "A1", "B1"] ... but just because it was simpler for me to implement. You showed quite nice improvement.

Comment: If you want to *keep* the full sub list as a value portion: `arr.map{|sa| [sa[0],sa]}.to_h`

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
arr = [[1, 'A1', 'B1'],[2, 'A2', 'B2'],[3, 'A3', 'B3']]
```

Code

```
p arr.map{|a|[a.first,a]}.to_h
```

Output

```
{1=>[1, "A1", "B1"], 2=>[2, "A2", "B2"], 3=>[3, "A3", "B3"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways I can think.

Use group_by(I personally choose this one), reduce and inject method.

```rb
arr = [[1, 'A1', 'B1'],[2, 'A2', 'B2'],[3, 'A3', 'B3']]

arr.reduce({}) { |result, record| result.merge!(record.first => record) }

Or 

arr.inject({}) { |result, record| result.merge!(record.first => record) }

OR

arr.group_by(&:first) # Short and sweet, I think you will pick this up.
```

Comment: The last one is fantastic!

Comment: Is original order inside of hash preserved if I use group_by?

Comment: `arr.group_by(&:first)` does not **quite** get the same result. This collects an array of elements, e.g. the first key/value pair is `1=>[[1, "A1", "B1"]]`, not `1=>[1, "A1", "B1"]` as desired.

Comment: You could slap a `.transform_values(&:flatten)` on the end to get the desired format. However, despite this being "clever", I'd rather opt for a basic solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67806630/1954610).

Comment: I would suggest to use reduce or inject in that case, the complexity will ne O(n), while `group_by` and then `transform_values` will be O(2n). So save time and computing power and user `reduce`.

Comment: Also `each_with_object` (which is often more natural than `inject`): `arr.each_with_object({}) { |a, h| h[a.first] = a }`